# How to relate internal energy to atomic motion?

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, energy

I am trying to conceptualize how atomic motion leads to the thermodynamically-defined internal energy (denoted as $U$ below) through some broad mathematical relationships. I get that the internal energy is effectively defined by the steric (or internal potential) energy (which includes bonded and non-bonded interactions of atoms in the system). Is this a valid conclusion, and *is there a more concise relationship*? I have outlined my reasoning below:

For a closed system, the internal energy ($U$) is related to the Helmholtz free energy ($A$) via temperature ($T$) and entropy ($S$):
\begin{equation}
A = U-TS
\end{equation}
The Helmholtz free energy is related to the canonical partition function ($Q_{\textit{NVT}}$), Boltzmann constant ($k_B$), and temperature ($T$):
\begin{equation}
A = -k_BT\ln Q_{\textit{NVT}}
\end{equation}
The canonical partition function is dependent on the Hamiltonian ($H$), which is a function of position ($\mathbf{x}$) and momenta ($\mathbf{p}$) of the atoms in the system:
\begin{equation}
Q_{\textit{NVT}} = \frac{1}{h^{3N}N!}\int_{\mathbf{x}}\int_{\mathbf{p}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{k_BT} H(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{x})\right) d\mathbf{p}\, d\mathbf{x}
\end{equation}
The Hamiltonian is a sum of kinetic ($T$) and potential energies ($E$):
\begin{equation}
H(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{x}) = T(\mathbf{p}) + E(\mathbf{x})
\end{equation}
The potential energy is defined by the sum of steric energies (bonded, $E_{\text{bonded}}$, and non-bonded, $E_{\text{non-bonded}}$):
\begin{equation}
E(\mathbf{x}) = E_{\text{bonded}}(\mathbf{x}) + E_{\text{non-bonded}}(\mathbf{x})
\end{equation}
In a classical system, atomic motion is governed by Newton's law:
\begin{equation}
\dot{\mathbf{p}} = \nabla_{\mathbf{x}} E(\mathbf{x}) = \nabla_{\mathbf{x}} H(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{x})
\end{equation}
since
\begin{equation}
T(\mathbf{p}) = \sum_i \frac{p_i^2}{2m_i} \ ,
\end{equation}
I get that $U$ is basically governed by $E(\mathbf{x})$.

(I would appreciate any good textbook references for further education.)

Comment: Could you try to reformulate this as a question that asks for something other than *"Am I correct?"*?

Comment: @ACuriousMind: yes, pretty much a "Am I correct"? I thought we were supposed to demonstrate our own effort in our posts.

Comment: Yes, showing effort is good...but questions which have *"Yes, this is correct"* as a potential answer aren't, because: a) that's too short to even type as an answer and b) very few people will have exactly your approach, so the question is unlikely to help anyone else.

Comment: @ACuriousMind, I have added a more general question, which is whether this is the most concise relationship. I hope this can garner a broader range of responses.

Comment: How does this work for an ideal gas where $E({\bf x}) = 0$?  Does one need to consider the walls in that case?

Comment: @garyp, very good point and suggestion about the wall...that's exactly the type of feedback I was hoping for. A pressure force induced by the walls, or alternatively a set of initial conditions would have to be prescribed. Also, $E(\mathbf{x})$ might be approximated by a hard-sphere model. Those would be my thoughts.

Comment: I wonder about an open system (no walls) ideal gas.  I suppose one uses the grand partition function, but now (I think) $E({\bf x})$ really seems to be identically zero everywhere.

Comment: @garyp, I guess while $\dot{\mathbf{p}}=0$ on account of $E(\mathbf{x})=0$, $T(\mathbf{p})$ need not be zero so long as $\mathbf{p}$ is initially specified by the Maxewell-Boltzmann distribution?

Comment: I'm no expert by any means, but I've always associated internal energy with temperature and kinetic energy.  I'm curious to see how it works out associating $U$ with potential energy.  (I can't see it at the moment).

Comment: @garyp, that is another good point...it is in the partition function and Helmholtz free energy but it's true that I might need to consider the explicit dependence in the kinetic and potential energies.

Comment: I find your question very interesting, I have been considering this myself some time. I agree with your formulation but I do not follow your conclusions. How can you conclude that U is fully determined by E(x)? It makes sense that the system behavior is determined by the interactions between molecules, but the kinetic energy of the particles, i.e. their momenta, is essentially independent of their relative positions and hence unrelated to E(x). How do you conclude U is governed by E(x)?